# CreateRemoteThread() fails with Access Denied (0xc00000005)

Tags: createremotethread

`CreateRemoteThread()` runs successfully for "32 bit caller process - 32 bit target process", but fails with Access Denied (0xc00000005) for "x64 caller process - x64 target process" :

- handle of target process received with flags `PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ`
- both processes are services and run under the Local System Account
- both processes are really 64bit - compiled by Visual Studio 2012 (Platform x64)
- OS - Windows Server 2016

Thanks!

Comment: `0xc0000005` (not 0xc00000005) means `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION`, not `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

Comment: Badro Niaimi, Great Thanks!!!!